# Mocking findOneBy"field" in doctrine2 with PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, doctrine-orm, mocking, phpunit

If I mock the repository method `find` I get the expected results,
but if I call either `findBy`, `findOneBy`, `findOneById` I always get `null`.

Code example:

```
$mock->expects($this->once())
                ->method('getId')
                ->will($this->returnValue(1));
$mockRepository->expects($this->any())
                         ->method('findBy') //if here I use 'find' works for all other cases always null
                         ->will($this->returnValue($mock));
```

Is there a reason why this happen?
Is it possible to mock the "magics" method of Doctrine2 like `findById` or `findOneById`?
If yes, what is wrong in my approach?

Comment: I guess you have to mock the `__call` method

Comment: The `__call` make a call to `findBy` or `findOneBy`

Comment: Since you are using a mock, unless you use partial mock, the __call method (or any other method of the mocked object) do not call the original method, but returns null by default

Comment: Yeah. You re right. I give it a try. Anyway from code I call findOneBy findBy

Comment: Hi @Raffaello if mine or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @Matteo, not at all, I just suspended the test suite for a while because I had to working on something else with higher priority.

Comment: ok, let me know if i can help you on this topic :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in the comment, is possible with mocking the magic method call. As Example:

```
 // Mocked return value
 $mock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getId')
            ->will($this->returnValue(1));

 // Example of repo mocking
 // $mockRepository= $this->getMock('Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository', array(), array(), '', false);

$this->mockRepository
->expects($this->at(1))
->method('__call')
->with('findBy')
->will($this->returnValue($mock));
```

Hope this help